# SQL query error from case when statement with subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST_TEMPLATE 
@TEMPLATE_TYPE INT=NULL
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT 
      TEMPLATE_ID,
      TEMPLATE_NAME    
   FROM 
      BDC_TEMPLATES
   WHERE 
      TEMPLATE_CAN_BE_APPLIED_TO IN (
            CASE 
              WHEN @TEMPLATE_TYPE=0 OR @TEMPLATE_TYPE=1 THEN  @TEMPLATE_TYPE  -- 0:EMAIL & LETTER , 1: EMAIL              
              WHEN @TEMPLATE_TYPE=2 THEN (SELECT DATA FROM UDF_DP_SPLIT_STRING('0,2', ',')) -- 2: LETTER
              ELSE TEMPLATE_CAN_BE_APPLIED_TO             
            END)  
END
```

Above stored procedure returns following error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TEST_TEMPLATE, Line 6
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

when executed with following inputs:

```
exec TEST_TEMPLATE 2
```

I am using the `IN` clause in the `WHERE` condition because when `@Template_Type` is '2', `Template_can_be_applied_to column` can be any one of the values 0 and 2.

Comment: SELECT DATA FROM UDF_DP_SPLIT_STRING('0,2', ','), this select statement return > 1 records, you might need to join it with key to make sure only 1 record is selected and output it

Comment: i am expecting more than one records from there that's why i have 'In' clause in the where condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can't use `INT` variable with `IN` statement, you need to use table variable with `SELECT` statement.

**UPDATE** You can’t use a scalar variable in the `IN` statement like record set. However if this variable has a single data value (as I think this is what you are trying to do) is OK.
In this case the solution provided by @ah_hau  to use equality sign “`TEMPLATE_CAN_BE_APPLIED_TO = @TEMPLATE_TYPE`” is better.

Secondly you can't have multiple records returned in the `CASE` statement. In order to achieve what you trying to do you need to use conditional `OR` and `AND` statements such as below:

```
WHERE (
       (@TEMPLATE_TYPE=0 OR @TEMPLATE_TYPE=1) 
        AND TEMPLATE_CAN_BE_APPLIED_TO IN (SELECT col FROM [your table variable])
      ) 
OR   (
       @TEMPLATE_TYPE=2 
   AND TEMPLATE_CAN_BE_APPLIED_TO IN (SELECT DATA FROM UDF_DP_SPLIT_STRING('0,2', ','))
     )
```

Answer (score 1):

let's see if this help

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST_TEMPLATE 
@TEMPLATE_TYPE INT=NULL
AS
BEGIN
SELECT TEMPLATE_ID,
        TEMPLATE_NAME    
        FROM BDC_TEMPLATES
WHERE (TEMPLATE_CAN_BE_APPLIED_TO = @TEMPLATE_TYPE AND (@TEMPLATE_TYPE=0 OR @TEMPLATE_TYPE=1))
OR (TEMPLATE_CAN_BE_APPLIED_TO IN(SELECT DATA FROM UDF_DP_SPLIT_STRING('0,2', ',') AND @TEMPLATE_TYPE=2)
OR (@TEMPLATE_TYPE>3)

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
 WHEN @TEMPLATE_TYPE=2 THEN (SELECT DATA FROM UDF_DP_SPLIT_STRING('0,2', ','))
```

The `SELECT` statement returns more than one row of DATA. As I see it, `UDF_DP_SPLIT_STRING` does return two values, 0 and 2 which returns the error.

Comment: I am aware of that, please read my comment for what i am trying to acheive